# ASP.net MVC 3 Edit/Delete issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

So I just finished working the project at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489. I am trying to create a CRUD for use with an external database that already exists and I am just using the project as a guide for my own work. I have been able to change certain variable names and connections to connect with the database that I am trying to work with and I have even displayed the data I want using the index method. I have also been able to get the create method working and I am able to create new data in the DB I am working with. Unfortunatlty I have not been able to pull data in when using the Edit or Delete methods or save/delete after I have made the changes I want.

For example when I press the edit button it should pull the record that I clicked on so that I could edit a particular records information but instead it threw an error saying that this variable cannot accept a null value which is why I changed the int to a string in the edit delete methods.  **This part is solved**

I think the issue has something to do with the Edit and Delete methods not pulling the recordset when I tell it to. Does anyone have any idea why it's not pulling the record sets when I edit/delete or saving my changes after I tell it to save?

I have posted my PaController class which has my CRUD methods in it for diagnosis as well as my iamp_mapping class file which has the 3 fields I need to work with. I am 90% sure I am doing something wrong with the controller, but if you need anymore code/information about the issue please leave me a note I will be checking back A LOT because I am soo stuck! Thanks so much for your help!

### PaController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DBFirstMVC.Models;
using System.Data;

namespace DBFirstMVC.Controllers
{
    public class PaController : Controller
    {
        PaEntities db = new PaEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Pa/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (var db = new PaEntities())
            {
                return View(db.iamp_mapping.ToList());
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Pa/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /Pa/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Pa/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(iamp_mapping IAMP)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new PaEntities())
                {
                    db.iamp_mapping.Add(IAMP);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Pa/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            using (var db = new PaEntities())
            {
                return View(db.iamp_mapping.Find(id));
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Pa/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(string id, iamp_mapping IAMP)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new PaEntities())
                {
                    db.Entry(IAMP).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Pa/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            using (var db = new PaEntities())
            {

                return View(db.iamp_mapping.Find(id));
            }
        }

        //
        // POST: /Pa/Delete/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(string id, iamp_mapping IAMP)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new PaEntities())
                {
                    db.Entry(IAMP).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### iamp_mapping

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DBFirstMVC.Models
{
    public partial class iamp_mapping
    {
        public string PA { get; set; }
        public string MAJOR_PROGRAM { get; set; }
        public string INVESTMENT_AREA { get; set; }
    }

}
```

### Edit View Code

```
@model DBFirstMVC.Models.iamp_mapping

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>iamp_mapping</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PA)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PA)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PA)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MAJOR_PROGRAM)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MAJOR_PROGRAM)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MAJOR_PROGRAM)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.INVESTMENT_AREA)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.INVESTMENT_AREA)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.INVESTMENT_AREA)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

### Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<DBFirstMVC.Models.iamp_mapping>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            PA
        </th>
        <th>
            MAJOR PROGRAM
        </th>
        <th>
            INVESTMENT AREA
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MAJOR_PROGRAM)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.INVESTMENT_AREA)
        </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PA }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PA }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PA })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

The ActionLink is what I had to fix, when I first posted the question it looked like this

`@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })`

I changed it to the actual primary key PA and deleted the comments. This fixed the problem of data not filling in when trying to edit a row!

```
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.PA }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.PA }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.PA })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

### Delete.cshtml

```
@model DBFirstMVC.Models.iamp_mapping

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

<h2>Delete</h2>

<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this?</h3>
<fieldset>
    <legend>iamp_mapping</legend>

    <div class="display-label">PA</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PA)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">MAJOR_PROGRAM</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MAJOR_PROGRAM)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">INVESTMENT_AREA</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.INVESTMENT_AREA)
    </div>
</fieldset>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

### Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace DBFirstMVC
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Pa", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `db.iamp_mapping.Find(id)` work when iamp_mapping doe snot have an int Id property?

Comment: That's a good question Henk I was wondering that as well and I actually changed id to IAMP when I was trying to fix the errors should I change it to PA or Major_Program or Investment_Area will something like that work? I thought that id was a kind of iterator but I could be completely wrong!

Comment: I think I figured out where the id comes from Henk, above I have added the code from my index class and explained what changes I made and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here appears that when you click on the edit button/link the Edit action will expect an id of type int (if you use int), however this can be switched as optional if you use int?...which is how the MVC behaves...your best bet here is to try using a url say something like http://urwebsite.com/Pa/Edit?id=[use a valid id]...with this you will have a id in your Edit action...

**Update**

I think the issue you are having here is that the Id value in the Edit action method is null...and the MVC engine is unable to recognize an id value from your Url pattern

So, the page where you have the edit link/button you can use something like

```
<a href="/Pa/Edit/@model.id">Edit</a>
```

If you have a for loop where you are displaying a collection of records...

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
```

`{`

`<a href="/Pa/Edit/@item.id">Edit</a>`

```
}
```

Also make sure that you have a routing configured for url pattern /Pa/Edit/{id}

You may wanna read this [Article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) if you want to know more about routing in mvc.

This will ensure that when a Get request is made to the edit action method, the id value will be recognized

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have posted the View code but I don't understand how I could use a url in the edit controller thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your quick response Nik I figured out part of the problem after reading your response. It wasn't exactly the routing but it did involve the index instantiating the id with the primary key. All I had to do was add <new {id = item.PA}> after the Edit action link. Then my data filled in the way it was supposed to. I have posted my index.cshtml above so the next person that has this problem can see how to fix it.

Comment: I do have one more question if you have time. The edit method is now working perfectly but the delete method is still being cranky. After I press delete it erases the data on the delete screen but not in the DB or on the index screen and it doesn't send me back to the index screen like it should. So in effect it doesn't delete! Arrg... I am so close. I have posted my delete view above for inspection. Thanks so much for your continued help you ROCK!!

Answer (score 0):

My link wouldnt pick the id up for some reason, so I found a solution from one course.
He added the fifth argument "null" to the function like this

`<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Account", new {id = account.Id }, null)</td>`
(text, action, controller, route value, null or HTML atribute)
this fixed it for me.